# Why is this composite of Lebesgue measurable functions Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

This is Exercise 8.10 of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*. Suppose $f$ is a real function on $\mathbb R^{2}$, $f_{x}$ is Lebesgue measurable for each $x$, and $f^{y}$ is continuous for each $y$. Here, $f_{x}$ and $f^{y}$ are the functions in $\mathbb R^{1}$ defined by $$f_{x}(y)=f^{y}(x)=f(x,y)$$ Suppose $g\colon \mathbb R^{1}\to \mathbb R^{1}$ is Lebesgue measurable, and put $h(y)=f(g(y),y)$. Prove that $h$ is Lebesgue measurable on $\mathbb R^{1}$.

I know that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, since $f$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions, namely the functions defined by
$$ f_{n}(x,y) = f(\lfloor nx\rfloor/n,y).$$

But I'm not sure if this helps, since composites of Lebesgue measurable functions need not be Lebesgue measurable. Replacing $f$ with a Borel function $g$ that agrees with $f$ almost everywhere in $\mathbb R^{2}$ is also dubious, since the image of the map $y\mapsto(g(y),y)$ has measure zero. How do I proceed with this problem?

Comment: You can change $R$ to $\mathbb R$ by typing \mathbb R between $ signs.

Comment: Did you see my comment? Please edit accordingly.

Comment: @zhw. sorry about that.. it's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

$$h_n(y) = f(\lfloor ng(y)\rfloor/n, y).$$

Then $h_n(y) \to h(y)$ everywhere. (Like your proof that $f$ is measurable, this follows from the hypothesis that each $f^y$ is continuous.) So it suffices to show each $h_n$ is Lebesgue measurable. Now observe

$$\tag1 h_n(y)=f(\lfloor ng(y)\rfloor/n, y) = \sum_{m\in \mathbb Z}f(m/n,y)\chi _{g^{-1}([m/n,(m+1)/n)}\,(y).$$

Each $f(m/n,y)$ is Lebesgue measurable by hypothesis, as is each $\chi _{g^{-1}([m/n,(m+1)/n)}$ because $g$ is Lebesgue measurable. Thus each summand in $(1)$ is Lebesgue measurable, hence so is the sum.